# What data to include in Weibull fit

Tags: excel, weibull-distribution

I have a set of inspection data that I want to fit to a weibull distribution to understand whether further inspection would provide much value.

For example, I have 2000 items of which we have recorded the thickness of 100. The original thickness was 2.0mm and of these 100 items 80 are still 2.0mm. 20 of them have varying degrees of reduced thickness, see readings below for measured thickness.

1.50,
1.54,
1.57,
1.58,
1.62,
1.66,
1.66,
1.67,
1.70,
1.72,
1.82,
1.84,
1.86,
1.88,
1.91,
1.92,
1.95,
1.95,
1.97,
1.97

Using excel I can approximate the weibull parameters however I want to understand if I should be including the 80x 2.0mm readings in the distribution to get a representative distribution or whether I should be just plotting the 20 readings that have 'corroded' and then some how accounting for the sample size later? The two methods return appreciably different beta and alpha values.

The end result I want to achieve is to return a probability of having less than 1.50mm in any of the remaining 1900 items. From that we can decide whether the risk is considerable enough to commit to further inspection.

Comment: You should include them, they are representative of the population.

Comment: However, they will not fit with the Weibull model nor any continuous model. A mixed distribution with a two component model -- a proportion 1-p of unreduced thicknesses and a proportion p of reduced thicknesses would be more appropriate, with a continuous distribution for those that are reduced might work (assuming there are no thicknesses that can be zero). However the reduced thicknesses cannot actually be Weibull, since thickness much be between 0 and 2, while the Weibull is unconstrained on the right. Possibly a truncated Weibull *might* work but I don't see a good reason to expect that.